# How can I get a computer to show the same shares when connecting to its IP address that appear when connecting to the name?

Tags: windows, network-share

On a workgroup Windows network if I `ping server` it correctly returns `10.47.20.2`.
If I browse for `\\server` (right click on windows icon, run and type in `\\server`) it only shows one folder (the folder the current computer has rights to edit).
If I browse `\\10.47.20.2` it shows all the shares on the `server` (but I can only get into the one that I have access to).

I want `\\server` to show the same shared folders as `\\10.47.20.2`. How?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen sometimes when there is confusion between IPv6 and IPv4 accessing SMB. Windows will resolve and prefer v6 over v4  for SMB, but will return v4 on ping.

Curious if you disable v6 if this issue automagically disappears?